# Flutter go_router Match error found during build

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

I'm receiving this error every time I try to open the dynamic link

[image]

But the error is only on IOS, in Android everything works perfectly.
This is how it navigates to needed page from the dynamic link:

```
Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FlashcardDetailedPage(
                    flashcard: flashcard,
                    deck: deck,
                    toDownload: true,
                  )),
  );
```

How to fix this?

Comment: The problem was that ios handled the deep links, so it was fixed by simply disabling deep linking in Info.plist, you should find the key there. Sorry, can not find it now.